# Get parent object from stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this class:

```
public class StructUserType extends UserType {

    MembersList membersList = new MembersList();

    public List<Member> getMembers() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(membersList.members);
    }

    static class MembersList {
        List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static class Member implements Identifiable {
        private Integer id;

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }    
}
```

And I have a `List` object:

```
List<SmbpUserType> userTypes = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want find `Member` which is equal to a certain id. I tried as follows:

```
Integer id = 1;
userTypes.stream()
                .filter(StructUserType.class::isInstance)
                .map(StructUserType.class::cast)
                .forEach(structUserType -> {
                    structUserType.getMembers()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(m -> m.getId() == id)
                            .findFirst().orElse(null);
                });
```

I want, when the filter in the internal stream runs and finds the first member, to return the parent element that this member contains, those `UserType`.

Analog in the classical style:

```
for (UserType userType : userTypes) {
            if (userType instanceof StructUserType) {
                List<StructUserType.Member> members = ((StructUserType) userType).getMembers();

                for (StructUserType.Member member : members) {
                    if (member.getId() == id) {
                        return userType;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `forEach` with `filter`, to find `StructUserType` instances that satisfy the condition of the inner stream pipeline. Then get the first element of the `Stream`, if such exists.

```
return
   userTypes.stream()
            .filter(StructUserType.class::isInstance)
            .map(StructUserType.class::cast)
            .filter(st -> st.getMembers()
                            .stream()
                            .anyMatch(m -> m.getId().equals(id)))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to return an `Optional<T>` rather than the value if present else `null`. This will document to the user of this method that there may or may not be a value present therefore they can use the `Optional<T>` methods to _safely_ get the value if present.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of forEach you can use a filter for the nested Stream.

At last you can return the first match or collect all matches

```
...
.filter(structUser -> structUser.getMembers()
                      .stream()
                      .anyMatch(member -> member.getId().equals(id))
       )
...
```